# Avoiding recursive template instantiation overflow in parallel recursive asynchronous algorithms

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, recursion, c++14

This issue is easier to explain through a simplified example *(since my real situation is far from "minimal")*: given a...

```
template <typename T>
void post_in_thread_pool(T&& f)
```

...function template, I want to create a *parallel asynchronous* algorithm that has a tree-like recursive structure. I am going to write an example of the structure below using `std::count_if` as a placeholder. The strategy I am going to use is as follows:

- If the length of the range I am checking is smaller than `64`, I will fall back to the sequential `std::count_if` function. **(0)**
- If it's bigger or equal than `64`, I will spawn a job in the thread pool that recurses on left half of the range, and compute the right half of the range on the current thread. **(1)**

  - I will use an atomic shared `int` to "wait" for the two halves to be computed. **(2)**
  - I will use an atomic shared `int` to accumulate the partial results. **(3)**

Simplified code:

```
auto async_count_if(auto begin, auto end, auto predicate, auto continuation)
{
    // (0) Base case:  
    if(end - begin < 64)
    {
        continuation(std::count_if(begin, end, predicate));
        return;
    }

    // (1) Recursive case:
    auto counter = make_shared<atomic<int>>(2); // (2)
    auto cleanup = [=, accumulator = make_shared<atomic<int>>(0) /*(3)*/]
                   (int partial_result)
    {
        *accumulator += partial_result; 

        if(--*counter == 0)
        {
            continuation(*accumulator);
        }
    };

    const auto mid = std::next(i_begin, sz / 2);                

    post_in_thread_pool([=]
    {
        async_count_if(i_begin, mid, predicate, cleanup);
    });

    async_count_if(mid, i_end, predicate, cleanup);
}
```

The code can then be used as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v(512);
std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

async_count_if{}(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
/*    predicate */ [](auto x){ return x < 256; }, 
/* continuation */ [](auto res){ std::cout << res << std::endl; });
```

---

The problem in the code above is `auto cleanup`. Since `auto` will be deduced to a unique type for every instantiation of the `cleanup` lambda, and since `cleanup` capture `cont` by value... an infinitely big nested lambda type will be computed at compile-time due to the recursion, resulting in the following error:

> fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jYvZAVL44brKCNDF)

Conceptually, you can think of the type being built up roughly like this:

```
cont                                // user-provided continuation
cleanup0<cont>                      // recursive step 0
cleanup1<cleanup0<cont>>            // recursive step 1
cleanup2<cleanup1<cleanup0<cont>>>  // recursive step 2
// ...
```

**(!)**: keep in mind that `async_count_if` **is just an example**, to show the "tree-like" recursive structure of my real situation. I am aware that an asynchronous `count_if` could be trivially implemented with a single atomic counter and `sz / 64` tasks.

---

I would like to **avoid the error**, **minimizing any possible run-time or memory overhead**.

- One possible solution is using `std::function<void(int)> cleanup`, which allows the code to compile and run correctly, but produces sub-optimal assembly and introduces extra dynamic allocations. [**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IFvxwXx6mkieWjeQ)

  - Another possible solution is using a `std::size_t` template parameter + specialization to artificially limit `async_count_if::operator()`'s recursion depth - this unfortunately can bloat the binary size and is quite inelegant.

What bothers me is that I know the size of the range when I call `async_count_if`: it is `std::distance(i_begin, i_end)`. If I know the size of the range, I can also deduce the number of required counters and continuations : `(2^k - 1)`, where `k` is the depth of the recursion tree.

Therefore, I think that there **should be a way of pre-computing a "control structure"** in the first invocation of `async_count_if` and pass it down to the recursive calls by reference. This "control structure" could **contain enough space for `(2^k - 1)` atomic counters and `(2^k - 1)` cleanup/continuation functions**.

I unfortunately could not find a clean way to implement this, and decided to post a question here as it seems like this problem should be common while developing asynchronous parallel recursive algorithm.

**What's an elegant way of dealing with this issue without introducing unnecessary overhead?**

Comment: i must be missing smth very obvious but why do you need multiple counters and structures? you can precompute total counter of iterations (if im not mistaken) and share it along with accumulator throughout all iterations

Comment: @dyp: could you post an example please? Even if I decide between two continuations at runtime, the full type for both will be recursively deduced.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Ah sorry, I had to draw this in order to see that each node in the tree needs log(N)*state for the contiuation that is pushed to the thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must be missing smth very obvious but why do you need multiple counters and structures? you can precompute total count of iterations (if you know your base case) and share it along with accumulator throughout all iterations, a la (had to modify your simplified code a bit):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
auto post_in_thread_pool(T&& work)
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, work);
}

template <class It, class Pred, class Cont>
auto async_count_if(It begin, It end, Pred predicate, Cont continuation)
{
    // (0) Base case:  
    if(end - begin <= 64)
    {
        continuation(std::count_if(begin, end, predicate));
        return;
    }

    const auto sz = std::distance(begin, end);
    const auto mid = std::next(begin, sz / 2);                

    post_in_thread_pool([=]
    {
         async_count_if(begin, mid, predicate, continuation);
    });

    async_count_if(mid, end, predicate, continuation);
}

template <class It, class Pred, class Cont>
auto async_count_if_facade(It begin, It end, Pred predicate, Cont continuation)
{
    // (1) Recursive case:
    const auto sz = std::distance(begin, end);
    auto counter = make_shared<atomic<int>>(sz / 64); // (fix this for mod 64 !=0 cases)
    auto cleanup = [=, accumulator = make_shared<atomic<int>>(0) /*(3)*/]
                   (int partial_result)
    {
        *accumulator += partial_result; 

        if(--*counter == 0)
        {
            continuation(*accumulator);
        }
    };

    return async_count_if(begin, end, predicate, cleanup);
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> v(1024);
    std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

    async_count_if_facade(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
    /*    predicate */ [](auto x){ return x > 1000; }, 
    /* continuation */ [](const auto& res){ std::cout << res << std::endl; });
}
```

---

Some [demo](http://cpp.sh/3ovxk)

Comment: if you mean the user provided continuation then you are wrong, sorry. Its called only when atomic counter reaches 0, other times only auxilary `cleanup` accumulator is called

Comment: Though I had exactly same thought about original code after initial reading

Comment: I'm talking about your code, not the OP's?  Yours calls the continuation repeatedly.  Oh wait, you have a facade right after your code that was hidden behind a scroll bar....

Comment: My question was poorly worded - `async_count_if` was just an example to show the structure of a more complicated asynchronous algorithm *(that would be far from a "minimal example")* which requires the "tree-like recursive splitting" structure that I used in my example. I upvoted your answer nonetheless as my original question is flawed - I will clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of atomic integers to synchronize is shared mutable state.  Shared mutable state kills performance in parallel algorithms.  Your shared state is shared over *every thread*.

Don't do that.

```
template<class T>
auto sink_into_pointer( T* target ) {
  return [target](T x){*target=x;};
}
template<class T>
auto sink_into_promise( std::promise<T>& p ) {
  return [&p](T x){p.set_value(x);};
}
void async_count_if(auto begin, auto end, auto predicate, auto continuation) {
  // (0) Base case:  
  if(end - begin < 64)
  {
    continuation(std::count_if(begin, end, std::move(predicate)));
    return;
  }

  std::promise< int > sub_count;
  auto sub_count_value = sub_count.get_future();

  auto sub_count_task = sink_into_promise(sub_count);
  // (1) Recursive case:
  const auto mid = std::next(i_begin, sz / 2);        

  post_in_thread_pool(
    [sub_count_task]()mutable
    {
      async_count_if(i_begin, mid, predicate, sub_count_task);
    }
  );

  int second_half = 0;
  auto second_sub_count = sink_into_pointer(&second_half);

  async_count_if(mid, i_end, predicate, second_sub_count);

  continuation( second_half + sub_count_value.get() );
}
```

In this case, the only shared state between threads is the values returned via the `packaged_task`s, and the thread pool manager.

When writing parallel code, your goal should be to maximize parallelism more than you maximize speed within a given thread.  Contention of shared resources and the like are going to cause worse scaling problems than following a function pointer once per thread.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but [this does not solve the original problem](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jywdA7zdbWjN3otp). Keep in mind that `async_count_if` is just an example: I know it can be implemented by simply splitting the count in separate tasks, but I'm interested in keeping the "tree-like" splitting recursive structure *(as that's what I have to use for another, more complicated algorithm)*.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Ah yes.  Well, fixed.  Your case is a bit trickier, as you fundamentally are passing your chain of continuations down.  [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Alb6PFSBliekaFFh)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo   You could avoid allocation in a `std::function` based solution in practice by wrapping and storing a `std::ref(continuation)` within the recursions (only do this once).  `sizeof(std::ref(continutation))` will fit within the small buffer optimization of any decent `std::function`.  And as we only execute `continuation` once, the call overhead of `std::function` should be ignorable.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the template recursion problem with something like this :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T> auto post_in_thread_pool(T &&work) {
  std::async(std::launch::async, work);
}

template <class Terminal_T> struct Accumulator {
  std::shared_ptr<atomic<int>> counter;
  std::shared_ptr<atomic<int>> accumulator;
  Terminal_T func;
  std::shared_ptr<Accumulator> parent;

  void operator()(int value) {
    *accumulator += value;
    if (--*counter == 0) {
      if (parent)
        (*parent)(*accumulator);
      else
        func(*accumulator);
    }
  }
};

template <class T>
auto make_shared_accumulator(T func, int nb_leaves,
                             std::shared_ptr<Accumulator<T>> parent = nullptr) {
  return make_shared<Accumulator<T>>(
      Accumulator<T>{make_shared<atomic<int>>(nb_leaves),
                     make_shared<atomic<int>>(0), func, parent});
}

template <class Begin_T, class End_T, class Predicate_T, class Continuation_T>
auto async_count_if(Begin_T begin, End_T end, Predicate_T predicate,
                    Continuation_T continuation) {
  auto sz = end - begin;

  // (0) Base case:
  if (sz < 64) {
    (*continuation)(std::count_if(begin, end, predicate));
    return;
  }

  // (1) Recursive case:
  auto counter = make_shared<atomic<int>>(2); // (2)
  auto cleanup = make_shared_accumulator(continuation->func, 2, continuation);
  const auto mid = std::next(begin, sz / 2);

  post_in_thread_pool([=] { async_count_if(begin, mid, predicate, cleanup); });

  async_count_if(mid, end, predicate, cleanup);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v(512);
  std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

  std::vector<std::future<size_t>> results;

  auto res_func = [](int res) { std::cout << res << std::endl; };
  async_count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
                 /*    predicate */ [](auto x) { return x < 256; },
                 /* continuation */
                 make_shared_accumulator(res_func, 1));
}
```

[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f770f85432608188). It is not perfect, a lot of useless copies could be avoided by using reference wrappers (and probably other optimizations could 
be done), but I tried to keep the example explanatory more than optimized.

The problem is that it is not easy to adapt to a more complex dataflow with several degrees of different accumulators, which I suppose is your real case.

You are trying to implement a parallelized data computing pipeline. This is not a simple problem that you could solve with a syntax trick. You need a thread safe way to communicate between your tasks that is neither recursive nor blocking for the threads.

The standard library alone will not provide you enough for this. The best you could do would be a shaky implementation based on futures.

To get out of this trap, you need more tooling. You could think about using [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) to implement your computing model. You could also use experimental frameworks such as [Boson](https://github.com/duckie/boson) or [RaftLib](http://www.raftlib.io) (multi threading not yet implemented in this one). Or implement your own, but beware this is a lot of work to get it right.